# Import of "bourbon" doesn't work in Jekyll setup

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass, jekyll, bourbon

I'm using **Jekyll** to create a static website and want to use the framework `Bourbon` to build my CSS from.

I've installed **Jekyll** and want to install **Bourbon** by adding it to my **Gemfile** using `gem 'bourbon'` and running `bundle install`.

Now when I add the rule `@import 'bourbon';` to my SCSS file and start to run Jekyll by `jekyll serve -w` it starts, but when I modify my SCSS file the **Jekyll watcher** throws an error saying:

```
    Regenerating: 1 files at 2014-07-03 10:00:11   `Conversion error: There was an error converting 'css/main.scss'.`
...error:
    Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bourbon. Load path: /Users/mark/Code/markdejong.com/mistermark.github.com.jekyll/_sass
    Error: Run jekyll build --trace for more information.
```

What can be the problem here? Shouldn't it be possible to import it like this or doesn't **Jekyll** support this?

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you have a Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'jekyll'

gem 'bourbon'
gem 'neat'
```

Add this line to `_config.yml`

```
gems: [bourbon, neat]
```

Jekyll will require these gems automatically.

Just do for import:

```
@import 'bourbon';
@import 'neat';
```

Check Jekyll docs for more information
http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/

Answer (score 3):

Did you do a

```
bourbon install
```

In order to create the bourbon folder ?

[Bourbon's doc](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon#non-rails-projects) also says that for non rail app the import rule is :

```
@import 'bourbon/bourbon';
```

Comment: These steps are unnecessary when Bourbon is installed from RubyGems. Yeah, it's not documented. Edit: with RubyGems, the `@import` directive is `@import 'bourbon'`.

Comment: This is how I would do it when I don't want to use RubyGems. But in this particular case I do want to use RubyGems. So this solution (standard use) doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import Bourbon at the Ruby level, with `require 'bourbon`?
Or in your Sass configuration?

With Sass, to use Bourbon installed with RubyGems, you have to tell the following command (note the argument `-r bourbon`):

```
sass -r bourbon -w css:sass
```

I do not know Jekyll, but it's perhaps a clue?

Comment: I did try to import with `require 'bourbon'`, but then it doesn't get recognized by **Jekyll**. That's the problem I'm facing now.